# SVN unfuddle can checkout

Tags: svn

Please someone help me to resolve my problem in svn. I can't checkout. I was just committing and checking out yesterday in other computer. The I try to checkout all the files here in my computer but it always fail.

Here is the message

```
Error: OPTIONS of 'http://mydomain.unfuddle.com/svn/myfolder': 200 OK (http://mydomain.unfuddle.com)
```

any advise or suggestions please

Comment: I have found this link.. maybe it can help..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239370/tortoise-svn-subversion-update-error

:)

Comment: Should be on Stackoverflow

Comment: I already try to turn off firewall but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your SVN client is getting a non-WebDAV response from the SVN server.

Is that a valid, working path to a SVN repository?  (*hint: probably not*)

Some things to check:

- Does it really use http, and not https?  That'd be a bit insane for a WebDAV SVN session, passing credentials in plain text.
- Have you tried adding a trailing slash (`.../svn/myfolder/`)?  WebDAV can be picky about slashes.